# Dados Não Passam Antes do Submit

Tags: php, html, jquery

boa tarde.
Sou novo aqui no fórum e novo em programação e estou empacado em uma ação.

Estou chamando uma janela modal para que o usuário digite algumas informações e ao clicar em salvar as informações vão para inputs dentro do form e o form é submetido.

O problema é que quando depuro o código tudo acontece no momento que devia, mas quando o código roda normal as informações não entram nos inputs e a query quebra. Como se o submit fosse primeiro que a atualização.

Gostaria de entender o que estou fazendo de errado e por que isso acontece.

Código:

1º Crio junto com a pagina o input vazio:

```
<input type='text' value='' id='vN'>
```

2º No evento click do botão na janela modal o Jquery abaixo move a informação do campo da janela modal para o input no form e chama o submit:

```
$("#vN").val($("#numNegocio").val());
$("#btSalvar").click();
```

3º O valor do input seria usado na função de salvamento em PHP, mas quando chega neste momento a informação já não está mais no input:

```
$n01 = isset($_POST['vv'])?$_POST['vN']:"";
```

Comment: Olá Carlos, seria melhor postar mais código que você está utilizando. Apenas estes que você inseriu abrem uma gama de possibilidades que possam ser os erros.

Comment: Se o seu modal estiver dentro do formulário no código, todos os inputs pertencerão ao form e você não precisará fazer essa transposição de valores.

Comment: Um dos problemas está relacionado com o `<input type='text' value='' id='vN'>` que não tem um `name`, logo o php não vai identifica-lo. O certo seria `<input type='text' value='' id='vN name='vN'>`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Infelizmente ele não está dentro do mesmo formulário, por uma limitação minha que não consegui formatar o modal corretamente quando o coloquei dentro do formulário. Desculpe a minha nubisse ... Estou começando com web agora.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Andrei, show de bola!!! Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado! Só inclui o name e funcionou exatamente como devia. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueJr legal! Que bom que funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado pelo Andrei Coelho, o problema estava na ausência do `name` no elemento. Com isso o `$_POST['vv']` não estava recebendo o valor do campo. É só adicionar o name:

```
                                     ↓↓↓
<input type='text' value='' id='vN' name='vN'>
```